# How to evaluate <%=SessionMessages.contains(renderRequest.getPortletSession(),"...")%> in EL

Tags: jsp, liferay, el

I need to use no scriplets in my code. How can I change this line?

```
<c:if test='<%=SessionMessages.contains(renderRequest.getPortletSession(),"author-added-success")%>'>
    <liferay-ui:success key="author-added-success" message="Author has been added successfully." />
</c:if>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't used Liferay for some time now, but according to my experience, the whole damn thing is based on putting code directly to JSP, so it can be pretty hard (if not impossible) to find out how to avoid that. Maybe it's better with Liferay 7, but up to 6.2, you are IMHO doomed.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek, What in the world for!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken: In this case you can totally omit the `<c:if>` tag: `<liferay-ui:success/>` will not display anything if the `key` is not found.

Granted, this doesn't answer the question to the letter, but it might solve the problem - depending on if you have other cases where you still would have the same or a similar problem.